# Graph database implemented using key value store

Tags: replication, graph-databases, key-value-store, nosql

I have a requirement for a graph database that needs to be backed-up and potentially accessed at a lower level of abstraction. It is also must be distributed for the sake of load balancing, (single master replication will do).

I know that it is possible to implement a graph database using a self-referencing key-value store. The Git object database is an example of this pattern. One of the frustrating things I find about most graph databases is that they do not "disclose" their underlying persistence layer in public api.

Do any replicated graph databases exist that allow for an underlying key-value stores to be "plugged-in" or accessed directly?

Comment: Gremlin/Tinkerpop is implemented on top of cassandra and you should be able in theory be able to access the underlying data storage.

Comment: @murungu this article [building-a-graph-database-on-a-key-value-store](https://www.tigergraph.com/2018/11/15/building-a-graph-database-on-a-key-value-store/) explains why using a graph database abstraction over a key value store database is a bad idea. They also explain a bit how the underlinings work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addition to Gremlin/Tinkerpop, mentionned by @amirouche above, I'm aware of two solutions:

[Redis](https://redis.io), completed by its [Graph Module](https://github.com/swilly22/redis-graph), matches your description.

[Cayley](https://github.com/cayleygraph/cayley) could also be a solution as it provides graph features over various SQL and NoSQL backends, some of them supporting distributed mode (Postgresql, MySQL, MongoDB, CockroachDB)